# iOS crash with UIMoreNavigationController

Tags: ios, uikit

I am getting a crash in my iOS Storyboard app which is easily reproducible.

When I enable Zombie Objects, this is the crash message I get.

```
2023-08-09 21:25:30.736022+1000 ThingyTwo[31860:4546795] *** 
-[UITabBarController removeChildViewController:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x14b830000
(lldb)
```

It happens when:

1. A UITabBarController is placed within a UINavigationController.
2. The UITabBarController has more than 5 view controllers, which then internally uses a UIMoreNavigationController to display the remainder.
3. The UINavigationController is removed from the view hierarchy.

It doesn't crash 100% of the time, usually somewhere between 20% and 80%.

I have created a bare-bones implementation almost entirely as a storyboard.

https://github.com/adamroyle/more-controller-crash

Run the project, click the "Show" button, and then click the "Dismiss" button. Keep repeating this until it crashes, it shouldn't take long.

Please let me know if you know of any simple workaround to this?

**Update 1:**

From [Apple Developer Forums](https://developer.apple.com/forums//thread/735354?answerId=761384022#761384022)

> Thanks for bringing this issue to our attention. This appears to be a bug, we'll investigate further.

**Update 2:**

I have found a workaround for now until Apple fixes the bug.

```
class NavigationController: UINavigationController {
    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        if !animated {
            setViewControllers([], animated: false)
        }
        
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Couple odd things...

First, I was wondering why you're embedding the `UITabBarController` in a `UINavigationController` when presenting it. So I tried presenting the tab bar controller directly, and... no tabs / view controllers? I'm assuming that's why you embedded it in the nav controller, but quick searching hasn't turned up any discussion on that...

Anyway, the `-[UITabBarController removeChildViewController:]: message sent to deallocated instance` crash appears to be a known issue.

***But...*** it is NOT related to your custom `DismissSegue`. If you pull-down to dismiss - instead of tapping the Dismiss button - same error.

So, a *possible* work-around...

First, change your `DismissSegue` class to this:

```
class DismissSegue: UIStoryboardSegue {
    override func perform() {
        if let tbc = self.source.parent as? UITabBarController,
           let vcs = tbc.viewControllers {
            vcs.forEach { vc in
                vc.removeFromParent()
            }
            tbc.dismiss(animated: true)
        }
    }
}
```

This definitely needs ***very thorough testing***. My *quick testing* seems to resolve the error / crash.

Second - although this may not be satisfactory behavior - we need to disable the "pull-down to dismiss" functionality.

We can do that by using this segue class:

```
class MyPresentSegue: UIStoryboardSegue {
    override func perform() {
        let vc = self.destination
        // prevent pull-down to dismiss
        vc.isModalInPresentation = true
        self.source.present(vc, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Then, of course, assign that class to your present segue as you did with the `DismissSegue`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The structure of my example project is just to easily demonstrate the crash. In my actual project the navigation controller is my root view controller and I get the crash when exiting the app. I also posted this to Apple Developer Forums and they have just responded saying it looks like a bug.